# how to print pdf using bluetooth printer in ionic 3

Tags: php, ionic3

I have created one pdf file in php. I want to print that pdf file in ionic 3 using a bluetooth serial printer plugin. For that one, I have written some code. Bluetooth serial plugin directly not support to print pdf data. so to avoid this problem i am using native printer plugin for printing, for connectivity i am using bluetooth plugin. but it is not working. Can u any one please help me how to do this.

```
goToTestprint()
{

----------

    this.bluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then(()=>{
          this.storage.get('printeraddress').then((getdata) => {
            if(getdata!=undefined && getdata!='undefined')
            {
               this.printercode=getdata;
               if(this.printercode!='')
                  {
                    let xyz=  this.bluetoothSerial.connect(this.printercode).subscribe((data) => {
                      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                            message: 'printer is connected',
                            duration: 10000,
                            position: 'top'
                            });
                          toast.present();
                      let options: PrintOptions = {
                          name: 'MyDocument',
                          printerId:this.printercode,
                          duplex: true,
                          landscape: true,
                          grayscale: true
                        };
                        var filepath='file://'+this.services.gettestbaseurlweb()+'admin/images/workorder/'+'INV1908172193'+'.pdf';
                        this.printer.print(filepath, options).then(onSuccess => {
                          console.log("on success print" +JSON.stringify(onSuccess));
                            let mno=this.alerCtrl.create({
                              title:"Print SUCCESS!",
                              buttons:['Dismiss']
                            });
                            mno.present();
                          xyz.unsubscribe();
                        }, onError => {
                          let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                            message: 'problem inprinting'+JSON.stringify(onError),
                            duration: 10000,
                            position: 'top'
                            });
                          toast.present();
                          console.log("on error print" +JSON.stringify(onError));
                        });
                   }, (error) => {
                   console.log('not Connected', error);
                   let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                                message: 'printer is not connected'+this.printercode,
                                duration: 5000,
                                position: 'top'
                              });
                               toast.present();

                   });
                  }
            }   
            else 
           console.log('printer code'+this.printercode);
          });
      },(error)=>{
        console.log('bluetooth is not enabled'+error);
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Sorry..! Bluetooth is not truned on, so printing is not possible.',
          duration: 10000,
          position: 'top'
        });
          toast.present();
      });   
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducaple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you try to pass the data that you used to generate in your pdf file to your mobile app and from that try to use that and format it in order for it to be printed by the plugin.